# Adding to an array that is a class property, with non-class item

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Here is some simple code that is not working.

i declare a class. the class contains an empty array. then, outside the class i try to populate it with a single item (another array) in a very simple way.

```
class Order {

public $productArr = array();
function __construct (){

}
}

$order = new Order();

$drumMachine = array('category' => 'musical instrument', 'brand' => 'Emu', 'model' =>      'sp1200');

$order->$productsArr[$drumMachine];
```

what's the correct way to do this? The $drumMachine would likely come from a $_SESSION['cart'] but i've simplified here.

I've done too much procedural programming…!

Answer (score 2):

Array keys can only be either `integer` or `string` (Reference: [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)).  You cannot have array as array key.

I believe you want the following:

```
$drumMachine = array('category' => 'musical instrument', 'brand' => 'Emu', 'model' => 'sp1200');
$order->productsArr['drumMachine'] = $drumMachine;
```

Then where you need to access it use:

```
$order->productsArr['drumMachine']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is quite off, you may want to boil back to the basics with PHP and learn the general syntax. However, here's what you're looking for.

```
$order->productArr[] = $drumMachine;
```

You're wanting to access productArr as an attribute directly, no $ necessary, and the [] = will add a new item to the END of the array

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `$drumMachine` is an object as well:

```
class OrderProduct
{
    public $category;
    public $brand;
    public $model;

    public function __construct($category, $brand, $model)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->brand = $brand;
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}

$drumMachine = new OrderProduct('musical instrument', 'Emu', 'SP1200');
```

Consider the following changes to the `Order` class:

```
class Order {
    private $productArr = array();

    public function addProduct(OrderProduct $product)
    {
        $this->productArr[] = $product;
    }
}

$order = new Order();
$order->addProduct($drumMachine);
```